# If X is a continuous random variable, it can have a discrete distribution function?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Today I encountered with constant random variable, that is,
$X(w) = c$ for all $w \in \Omega $

but its density function is

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1 &\text{if} &x=0 \\ 0 &\text{if} & x\neq 0\end{cases}$$

am I right ?

Comment: Not quite, because a discrete distribution needs $\sum_i p_i = 1$ but a continuous distribution needs $\int f(x)\, dx = 1$. But the Dirac delta function is a way of describing a distribution like this.

Comment: This is not correct, because the pdf of a function must INTEGRATE to $1$, and this function integrates to $0$.  If it were a discrete random variable you could have a probability MASS function like this, but for a continuous random variable you cannot have a a probability DENSITY function defined like this.  Instead, you would need to use the Dirac delta "function", which is a "generalized function" or "distribution" which is $0$ except at a point, but is infinite at that point, so that the total integral of the function is $1$.

Comment: If you had a sequence of random variables with $X_n$ uniformly distributed on $[-\frac1n,\frac1n]$ with density $2n$ on that interval,  then your $X$ would be $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}X_n$.  But see what happens to the density for large $n$.

Answer (score 0):

every discrete distribution can be informally thought of as continuous by using the theory of ditributions. A possible example for your case would be to have the PDF of X be a dirac delta function at c.

This entails that the integral of the pdf over a ball centered on c and with arbitrarily small radius will always give 1 and guarantee the RV is constant.

Hope this helps and i invite you to look into [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Link_between_discrete_and_continuous_distributions) of the wikipedia page on pdf's.

Comment: You are stretching "informally" a long way there (and using something that calls itself a "function" but is not).  Continuous distributions have properties that discrete distributions do not, and it is better to recognise this rather than informally wave such differences away.  If you are going to use approximations and limits, than do so, but this is similar to saying that every rational number is the limit of a sequence of irrational numbers

Answer (score 0):

You have a contradiction of terms. You say that X is a continuous random variable, but the fact that it can take only a countable number of values means that it is, in fact, a *discrete* random variable. A continuous random variable that cannot take an uncountable continuum of values is not a continuous variable. It doesn't really make sense to claim that a coin flip produces continuous outcomes, but has only two possible results. A continuous random variable, by definition, can take an uncountable continuum of values. If you can count the number of possible outcomes, the distribution is discrete and not continuous.

You could define a discrete random variable in discrete space using a probability mass function, or define it in continuous space using a Dirac delta function. Either way, the total probability must be 1, either by summing the discrete probability masses, or by integrating the delta function which is arbitrarily narrow but has finite, non-zero area underneath. The probability density function you propose in the question is *not* actually a PDF, since it does not have area 1.